# Method group behaving differently than lambda?

Tags: c#, moq

I am using `Moq` to mock some interface. Here it is:

```
var titleGenerator = new Mock<ITitleGenerator>();
titleGenerator.Setup(t => t.GenerateTitle()).Returns(Guid.NewGuid().ToString);

Console.WriteLine(titleGenerator.Object.GenerateTitle());
Console.WriteLine(titleGenerator.Object.GenerateTitle());
```

It prints the same value twice. But if I replace the second line with this:

```
titleGenerator.Setup(t => t.GenerateTitle()).Returns(() => Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

it returns unique values on each call.

I always thought method groups are just a shortcut to lambda expression. Is there any difference? I tried searching the documentations for any explanation. Can someone enlighten me?

It looks like the method group evaluates the expression once and somehow caches it? Or does it have something to do with `Moq`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is in the *inputs*.  In the first case the "method group" is actually a delegate for `Guid.ToString`.  But since it requires an *instance* as "input", the instance is part of the delegate expression, and so the same "input" is used each time.

It would be equivalent to:

```
var titleGenerator = new Mock<ITitleGenerator>();
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
titleGenerator.Setup(t => t.GenerateTitle()).Returns(g.ToString);
```

In the second case, the delegate *has no input*. The `Guid` instance is calculated *within the delegate*, so a new `Guid` is used each time.

Comment: Can you explain `the instance is part of the delegate expression`? It's a `Func<string` so how can it take inputs?

Comment: @EmperorAiman Delegates have a [`Target`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.target(v=vs.110).aspx) property that indicates the object that the instance method is invoked on.  In your first case the delegate references the `ToString` method on a specific `guid` instance.

Answer (score 9):

In your first example, you're passing the `ToString` function of a single `Guid`, which then gets called on every invocation.  It's equivalent to this:

```
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
titleGenerator.Setup(t => t.GenerateTitle()).Returns(guid.ToString)
```

In your second example, you're passing a function that first creates a new `Guid` and then invokes `ToString()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

For an equivalent example that might be easier to understand, the code:

```
var id = 1;
Func<string> f = id.ToString;
id = 2;
Console.WriteLine(f()); // 1
```

will write `"1"`, whereas:

```
var id = 1;
Func<string> f = () => id.ToString();
id = 2;
Console.WriteLine(f()); // 2
```

will write `"2"`.

In the **first case**, the delegate (`Func<>` instance) `f` is created with the value `1` as [`Target`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.target.aspx) and the method info for [`string int.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5.aspx) as [`Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.method.aspx). The later reassignment to `id` does not affect `f`.

In the **second case**, things will be more indirect. The compiler will generate a new method that corresponds to the `=>` arrow. The local variable `id` is **captured** or **closed over** (is in the **closure** of the lambda). That means, behind the scenes, `id` is really promoted to a `field` somewhere (compiler's choice). When your method mentions `id`, it really accesses that field. And the compiler-generated method corresponding to the `=>` arrow also reads that field. Now the `Func<>` is created with its `Method` property being this compiler-generated method. Because of all this, the result will be `"2"` here. That is the closure semantics of *anonymous functions* in C#.

Your original Moq example is just the same. The `Returns` overload in question takes an argument `Func<TResult> valueFunction` where `TResult` is `string` in your use. That `valueFunction` is what I called `f` in my simpler example.